# How to get the sum and get of JS constructive function

Tags: javascript

I've declared a constructor function as following

```
function student(i,n,a,d,g){
    // private
    var age= a;

    //data
    this.id= i;
    this.name= n;
    this.dept= d;
    this.grade= g;

    this.getAge = function(){
        return age ;
    }

    this.setAge = function(a){
        age = a
    }
}
```

and then I'd initialized the data as following

then I've tried to get the sum and average of grades, but it hasn't worked.

```
function sum(grade){
    var res=0;
    for(var i=0; i<grade.length; i++){
        res+=grade[i];
        return res ;
    }
    var avg= res / grade.length;    
}
```

Comment: `return res` in the loop stops the execution of the function immediately.

Comment: How are you calling `sum`? By the way, I think you mean "constructor" instead of "constructive function". Anyway, a "constructor" does not have a sum--how could it, since it's just a function? Do you mean the sum of the grade field of a number of instances created using that constructor? In that case, you need to keep track of all the instance, such as in an array somewhere. Also, you seem to have left out the part of your question following the line "and then I'd initialized the data as following".

Comment: You're right about constructor function indeed ,

Comment: You're right about constructor function indeed ,
the missing part is 
var std1 = new student (8,"Ammar",22,"SD",90);
var std2 = new student (9,"Ahmed",24,"EL",50);
var std3 = new student (10,"islam",29,"OS",60);
var std4 = new student (11,"Atta",28,"SD",80);
var std5 = new student (12,"Aya",25,"OS",70);

var studentArr =[];
studentArr.push(std1,std2,std3,std4,std5);

studentArr.forEach(function(element,index,Array){
 console.log("Name = " +element.name+", Dept= "+element.dept+" ,Grade = " +element.grade+"");
}) 

I do mean the sum of grade field

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to use the `return` inside loop because it will stop the loop just right after the first cycle. Also the function will be stopped in that moment and the `avg` variable won't be even set.

```js
function sum(grade) {
  var res = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) {
    res += grade[i];
  }
  var avg = res / grade.length;
  console.log(avg);
}
```